# Relation between $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(w2^{1/3})$

Tags: field-theory

I have the following exercise in my homework:

> Are $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(w2^{1/3})$ isomorphic, 
>   where $w = \textrm{cis}((2\pi)/3)$? Prove your answer.

I think they are, but I'm not sure how to define the proper isomorphism.
Any help would be appreciated — thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ken - $\mathrm{cis}\theta$ can be used to denote $e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @Math1000 I am so sorry, I had no idea. Changed. Is that better?

Comment: I didn't either. I had to look it up. The only time I've seen "cis" before is in chemistry :)

Comment: @Math1000 Heh, yeah, my only prior experience was in gender identity literature. Quite far afield!

Answer (score 0):

They are isomorphic since $2^{1/3}$ and $w2^{1/3}$ are both roots of the same irreducible polynomial.